# UITableViewCell always present at top of UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am attempting to recreate a button that is always present at the top of a `UITableView`, as seen in an application such as Spotify:

[image]

I am not sure how I should carry out recreating the "Shuffle Play" button. The button **must** be present at all times at the top of the `UITableView`. Any ideas? Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming there is only one section for the tableview. 
Create a view for the section header.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44.0f;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just shrink the size of the UITableView and add a view right above it that contains a UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a parent UIViewController that holds the button and a container view that has an embed segue to your UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button inside tableView header, than it will be always on top, and will never hide.